# c++: problem in getting input for fields in a class

Tags: c++

I am trying to assign values to fields in a class `courseInfo` by getting input from user.
i am using the following program.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class courseInfo
{
public:
   char courseCode[10];
   char courseName[80];
   int ECTS;
};
int main()
{
courseInfo c;
cout<<"\nEnter course details: ";

cout<<"\nCourse code: ";
cin>>c.courseCode;
cout<<"\nCourse name: ";
cin>>c.courseName;
cout<<"\nECTS: ";
cin>>c.ECTS;
return 0;
}
```

The console looks this when i run the program.

[image]

I enter the value for courseCode and the program does not wait for the user to enter courseName, it directly goes to ECTS.

why does this happen?
how can I rectify this?

Comment: `cin>>c.courseCode` reads a word, and `cin>>c.courseName` reads the next word. If you want to read a line instead of a word, google "read line C++".

Answer (score 1):

This occurs because when you input `phy 121`, `cin>>c.courseCode`reads **phy** while `cin>>c.courseName`reads **121**.

If you want to read the entire line, try this.

```
getline(cin, string)
```

Replace this where you want it to read a line instead of just a word.